# tensorflow prediction is low for the exact same data that's been used for training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

tensorflow 2.16.1

To detect the silence (little noise), I have trained a tensorflow model using several wave files.
All the wave files are Mono, 16kHz in PCM16 format.

MFCC is calculated using python_speech_features package for every 0.1 seconds of data.

```py
mfcc_feat = np.mean(mfcc(block, # An array of 1600 floats for 0.1 seconds of data
                         16000,
                         numcep=20,
                         winlen=160/16000,
                         winstep=160/16000,
                         nfilt=20),
                         axis=0)
```

The shape of final array X is (1500, 20) and the model is defined, compiled, and trained using

```py
# Define and compile the model
model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=(20,)),  # Input shape is 1D array of 20(mfcc) floats
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(20),
    layers.Dense(X.shape[0], activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, verbose=0)
```

[image: audio detection]

The first plot is testing sound file with an utterance of a word in the last.
The next two are the results of prediction using a threshold of 0.8 and they are varying.
One of the file that's been used for training is extracted from the test file itself.

The one small block in the second plot and two at the beginning of the third plot are the same as in the test file (silence_test2) but still prediction values are lower (<0.1, 0.4, 0.7). I could think of three possibilities:

1. mfcc is not calculated properly
2. model is not defined correctly
3. need more data while training

What's the reason and how prediction can be improved? Apart from this, suggestions are welcome in general.